# How to setup gitlab runner using VirtualBox - Linux on Windows

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

### Problem

I am trying to setup a gitlab runner on my local machine and the executor is VirtualBox - Linux Ubuntu. However, I spent more than 2 days without any success and ran into all kind of issues and none of the solutions on the internet helped.

The error I am getting now is:
    ERROR: Preparation failed: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [publickey none password], no supported methods remain

### What I did so far:

On My local machine (Windows 10 Enterprise)

- Enabled both ports 22 and 2200 for incoming connections.
- Created an id_rsa & id_rsa.pub and added it to GitLab. Copied to them another folder G:\ssh\  (I added my user and sshd user with full access)
- Added and registered GitLab-Runner under G:\GitLab-Runner folder
- I installed latest Virtualbox & setup Linux Ubuntu 18.04.1
- I set the GitLab-Runner service to run under my Administrator account (Without that I was running into another issues ~ If I remember correctly - the runner couldnt clone the virtual machines)
  On the Linux veritualmachine (Login required with username and password)
- I installed openssh
- Generated id_rsa & id_rsa.pub (Didnt add them to GitLab)
- Enabled Firewall and enabled sshd ports
- Enabled ports 22 (ssh) & 2200 ports as well
- Executed below code

  ```
  chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  chmod 700 ~/.ssh
  ```
- created ~/.ssh/authorized_keys and added the id_rsa file to it
- I Uncommented the below lines in sshd_config

  ```
  Port 22
  PubkeyAuthentication yes
  AuthurizationKeysFile      .ssh/autherized_keys .ssh_authorized_keys2
  ```

### File contents/config

config.toml (gitlab-runner)

```
    concurrent = 1
    check_interval = 0
    log_level = "debug"

    [session_server]
      session_timeout = 1800

    [[runners]]
      name = "dep-runner"
      url = "https://gitlab.com/"
      token = "gitlabrepository-key"
      executor = "virtualbox"
      [runners.ssh]
        user = "WindowsUser"
        password = "WindowsPassword"
        port = "22"
        identity_file = "G:/ssh/id_rsa"
      [runners.virtualbox]
        base_name = "DeploymentMachine"
        user = "deployment"
        password = "root"
        identity_file = "/home/deployment/.ssh/id_rsa"
        port = "22"
        disable_snapshots = false
      [runners.cache]
        [runners.cache.s3]
        [runners.cache.gcs]
```

DeploymentMachine is the linux ubuntu installed as virtual machine.

Information under [runners.ssh] is the credentials for my Windows 10 machine

Linux - authorized_keys file contains:

```
    ----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
       THE KEY
    ----END RSA PRIVATE KEY------
```

.gitlab-ci.yml contains

```
    # This file is a template, and might need editing before it works on your project.
    # Full project: https://gitlab.com/pages/plain-html
    pages:
      tags:
      - dep-tag
      stage: deploy
      script:
      - mkdir .public
      - cp -r * .public
      - mv .public public
      artifacts:
        paths:
        - public
      only:
      - master
```

So I am expecting it either to pass since it the script is just creating folders, or at least to fail because something wrong regarding the code (which I dont think in this case)

Any help is appreciated, and if more info needed please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The runners.ssh section should be the information of the vm you want to use. runners.virtualbox should only contain the base_name and disable_snapshots fields.

i also found that only this version worked : https://github.com/ayufan/gitlab-ci-multi-runner for the virtualbox executor at least in my experince.

Comment: Correct - `[runners.virtualbox]` section is wrongly configured. Should be something like : `[runners.virtualbox]
    base_name = "gitlab-runner"
    disable_snapshots = true`